# How are links like drive.google.com, app.codeable.io etc. achieved?

Tags: web-services, web

Websites that have sort of a secondary domain.

What are links like these called?

Can it be done trough code or is it a domain thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a coding question - this is related to network and DNS administration.

The "drive" part of "drive.google.com" is just a subdomain or machine name on the "google.com" domain. As far as DNS is concerned, it is even easier - these are just additional entries in your DNS configuration. There is almost nothing special that needs to be done.